# How do I find the murdered woman in Windhelm?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I start the Blood on the Ice quest?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41219/how-can-i-start-the-blood-on-the-ice-quest)

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38126/3) indicates that if the steward in Windhelm won't sell me the house or give me the quest to find the murderer, then I can start it by finding a body in the graveyard and talking to the guard.

I've visited the graveyard at night, but I can't find the body or the guard.  What should I do?  Or is that answer incorrect?

Comment: no not a duplicate  but ill admit its a branch off of it     i tried to ask me question in that page but it was taken off