# Blood On The Ice won't trigger at all

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to start blood on the ice quest and it just won't trigger. I have completed the civil war quest on jarl ulfric stormcloak's side. Everyone is talking about it in windhelm and susana the wicked is still alive in candlehearth hall. I am level 9. I have also pickpocketed tova shatter shield and got the key to hjerim and the quest still won't trigger. I also pickpocketed calixto and got his chest key, I got his butcher journal #2 and the quest will still not trigger. I have been to windhelm multiple times and I have been there between the times 7pm-7am. Please help because I do not want to start another save. (I didn't join the dark brotherhood or do the aventus arentino quest because I heard that it can mess up this quest).

Comment: Welcome to the community! Does this answer your question? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41219/how-can-i-start-the-blood-on-the-ice-quest

Comment: @Fredy31 it is very similar to mine because when I went into hjerim then it did say investigate investigation target, Is there a glitch where susanna never leaves?

Comment: This quest has multiple bugs associated with it. Do you have the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch for the PS4](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4073181) installed? Have you picked up one of the Beware the Butcher! pamphlets in Hjerim? See https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood_on_the_Ice#How_to_Start_the_Quest and https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood_on_the_Ice#Hjerim for what to check.