# Which house has the most overall display units?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I would like the house with the most weapon racks, wall plaques, display cases, mannequins, and book shelves.  Which house has the highest total combined of all four types?

Comment: Any house with 1 cupboard can store an infinite amount.

Comment: There is no limit to how much stuff you can put into a single container... a shack with a single barrel can store as much stuff as a mansion with 50 chests.

Comment: Yes but i am looking for weapon racks and mankins.

Comment: Then you should make your question more clear.

Comment: Sorry for that.

Answer (score 12):

According to [this chart on UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses)  The windhelm house has the highest amount of overall display types, with 12 bookshelves, 2 shield plaques, 7 weapon plaques, 1 weapon rack, 7 display cases, and 3 mannequins.

The only problem is you'll have to pick a side in the rebellion to obtain it, and it is [rather buggy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37697/why-cant-i-buy-the-windhelm-house) and may be unpurchasable.

Comment: I have finished the rebellion quests.Is that all you need to get that house?

Comment: @Ray you will also need to solve the murder quest.

Comment: What is the name of that quest?

Comment: @Ray Blood on ice

Comment: Tx for everything @yx

Comment: @Ray no problem, if you are satisfied with the answer, you should click on the checkbox next to it to accept it :)

Comment: Wow.  So far, my only house is in Whiterun.  I think after that, this one is probably the only one I'll ever need!  That is, until the completionist in me kicks in and I gotta buy 'em all.