# What are the requirements to obtain the purchasable house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What are all the requirements to obtain the house in Skyrim? I have already found the correct murderer and completed the blood on ice quest however the house is still not available for purchase.

Comment: Have you done any of the civil war? Does this link help? [Why can't I buy the Windhelm house (Hjerim)?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37697) Or the first part of this page: http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hjerim

Answer (score 1):

There is a major bug that a lot of players encounter in which all the requirements are completed however you still can not purchase the house. Sadly there is no known workaround at the moment. More information can be found on this thread: [Why can't I buy the Windhelm house (Hjerim)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37697/why-cant-i-buy-the-windhelm-house-hjerim?lq=1)